# JavaScript splitting string by date and grouping in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

well I have this array

```
let a = ["2020-09-13 10:00", "2020-09-13 11:00", "2020-09-14 10:00"];
```

and I want it to order like

```
{"2020-09-13": ["10:00","11:00"]},
{"2020-09-14": ["10:00"]}
```

I tried anything comes to my mind but I think I am a bit rusty, could you guys please bear a hand?

Comment: any other efficient ways is okay too I couldn't figure out which one is the best way to store them since the data depends on dates and their times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let a = ["2020-09-13 10:00", "2020-09-13 11:00", "2020-09-14 10:00"];

const result = a.map(elem => elem.split(" ")).reduce((accm, elem) => {
    const date = elem[0];
    const time = elem[1];

    let accmValues = accm[date];
    if (!accmValues) {
        accmValues = []
    }

    accmValues.push(time)

    accm[date] = accmValues
    return accm
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `String.split`, you can split the `date` & `time` value.

And using `Array.reduce`, you can group by the `date` value key.

```js
const a = ["2020-09-13 10:00", "2020-09-13 11:00", "2020-09-14 10:00"];
const result = a.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const timeArr = cur.split(' ');
  acc[timeArr[0]] ? acc[timeArr[0]].push(timeArr[1]) : acc[timeArr[0]] = [ timeArr[1] ];
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```